# HTML5: Playing Audio

Tags: django, html5-audio

I would like to play an audio in my Django app.. I am trying to include the audio but it doesn't seem to play..

I tried two things..
1)

```
<audio id="BillaTheme" autoplay>
     <source src="../media/audio/Billa2Theme.mp3"/>
</audio>
```

2)

```
MEDIA_URL = '/Users/Projects/beer/ThirdProject/media/'
<audio id="BillaTheme" autoplay>
     <source src="{{MEDIA_URL}}audio/Billa2Theme.mp3"/>
</audio>
```

Both doesn't seem to work. Need some guidance on this...

Comment: Does resource file loads normally (code 200 or 302)?

Comment: Check if your browser supports playing mp3 files (IE >=9, Chrome, Safari support it, other browsers don't).

Comment: I used both chrome and firefox...still doesn't work.. btw does the size of the file matter?

Comment: it gives me the code of 404 when it is not able to link..."GET /Users/Projects/beer/ThirdProject/media/audio/Billa2Theme.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 2452...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django Application server can't find your audio file. It can't find it on the path: "/Users/Projects/beer/ThirdProject/media/audio/Billa2Theme.mp3". Check the path and the name of file properly. It's case-sensetive - the path and the name of file.

Output your MEDIA_ROOT in a template and make sure that it is exactly you want.

If you use another web server to serve static files then check the access log of the server.

Answer (score 1):

Does your browser support mp3? Take a look at the "Audio Formats and Browser Support" table at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp)

You could also give a try to the nice & open-source [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).